# Remove drop arrow of mat-select

Tags: angular, angular-material

There is a way to remove the arrow of mat-select?

I need to remove it to center my option with the label : [image: select with arrow]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

just add

```
.mat-select-arrow {
    border: none;
   
}
```

to the component style's sheet or  the styles.scss of your angular app.
Caution this will remove every arrow in mat-select.
if you want to remove arrow for a few ones just add a class to `mat-form-field` and nest your class in the scss file.
You can find an example here [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-he4bss?file=src/styles.scss)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That's almost perfect, but there is a problem... When I do that, the option disapear too. I supposed that the arrow is linked with the option.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to remove it and the space that it is occupying try:

```
::ng-deep.mat-select-arrow {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: The ::ng-deep selector is considered deprecated and discouraged by the Angular team.

Answer (score 1):

for me the solution was:

```css
::ng-deep mat-select::after {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: The ::ng-deep selector is considered deprecated and discouraged by the Angular team.